# Does Boost Spirit X3 support left recursion?

Tags: parsing, recursive-descent, boost-spirit-x3, left-recursion

One of the shortcomings/implementation challenges of recursive-descent parsers is dealing with left recursion, e.g.

```
<expr> :=    <expr> '+' <num> 
          |  <num>
```

The parser needs to parse an expr before it can parse an expr...

Now, [Boost::Spirit::X3](https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/) generates [recursive descent parsers](https://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/spirit/introduction.html). Does that mean it doesn't support left-recursion, or does it have workarounds for it?

Note: Left recursion can (often? always?) be eliminated from the grammar beforehand (like in the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41548351/1593077)), but that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Spirit doesn't rewrite your grammar at all, it runs exactly what you've wrote.

Comment: So are you saying this kind of syntax would result in a compilation error? Runtime error?

Comment: Qi only tries to check for direct left recursion at compile time, while X3 does not do even this. The infinity recursion should (and will) lead to a crash with stack overflow at runtime.